# Kernel module to connect ps/2 keyboard to usb?

Tags: kernel, usb, keyboard, kernel-modules

Is it technically possible to write a kernel module to physically connect a PS/2 keyboard to a USB port using a passive converter? If not, why?

(If I simply wanted my keyboard to work I would buy an active adapter, but the purpose of this question is to learn something)

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Do you want to connect a PS/2 device to a USB port  **physically**? Or do you want to create a virtual USB device that actually corresponds to your PS/2 device which would be connected to a true PS/2 port? Please add proper details to your question.

Comment: I want to physically connect a keyboard with a ps/2 plug to a usb-port with a non-active converter. I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

No USB standard implements backwards compatibility with PS/2.  PS/2 mice which predate USB do not contain time-travelled USB descriptors.  Nor can an arbitrary USB port be accessed as a GPIO.

USB descriptors: https://blog.digital-scurf.org/posts/stm32-and-rtfm/

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gpio & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_banging

(Wiki links aren't going to be great, but the introductions here should give the idea).

Converting the opposite way round, passive USB to PS/2 converters require USB support in the USB input device, and recent USB devices don't bother with it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port#Conversion_between_PS.2F2_and_USB

Comment: This is wrong. Enabling "legacy usb" in BIOS let's you use passive USB/PS2 (pin to pin) converters. And they work on windows. No usb logic in them.

Comment: Congratulations. It would indeed be technically possible to write a kernel module that allows that to work. In fact you could write it in any language! Python would be a good example of a language where this program can be written in zero bytes. :-P.

Comment: Usually when I've seen "legacy USB" in BIOS, it's to allow using a USB device in an OS which only supports PS/2.  Did you check that disabling "legacy USB" actually stops this alleged antique wonder from working?  You might find the option is not actually necessary for this.

Comment: Pictures would also be very interesting :-).

Comment: https://5kw.dk/Hobby/electronics/connectors/usb_and_ps2.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Enabling "legacy usb" in BIOS let's you use passive USB/PS2 (pin to pin) converters. And they work on windows.

I've never tried with linux though.